# How to have two phonegap applications on one phone

Tags: android, mobile, web-applications, phonegap-build, phonegap

I created two applications with phonegap. I need to have both on my phone so i downloaded both apks. But everytime i try to install the missing application, it only overrides the existing one. How to have both on my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok that was quit simple: just give each application a uniqe *id* in the *config.xml*

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely using the same "id" in your config.xml file. Use a unique one for each app, such as:

id = "com.example.pictures"

id = "com.example.appTwo"

**Example config.xml snippet:**

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.example.appTwo" 
        versionCode = "1" 
        version     = "1.0.0">
```